# C# - how quickly do events fire?

Tags: c#, events, mousemove

I'm using the MouseMove event with Visual C# 2012.

How often does this event fire when I move the mouse? At the moment, it seems to be firing enough to run a paint event at a reasonable frame rate - but I need to know how often it fires, and whether this can be adjusted with some kind of system function or variable.

Thanks,

Barry Smith

Comment: In time of old (Win 3.1 etc) the frequency used to be up to 65536 in a minute = 18.2 events in a second

Comment: Hmm... So it's only limited by computer speed? Then why doesn't the software pump up the CPU power then? How do I change this? @Precious1tj Event's can't fire immediately. As I am constantly moving the mouse, according to your logic that means the computer is doing an infinite amount of calculations per second. This is of course impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Messages such as `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_PAINT` etc. are generated as fast as you let them as they are delivered in a different way to other messages. Probably worth reading this article for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/19/10249000.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a very useful answer :) - I would vote up if I could (<15 rep)